# Cumulative SUM based on ID

Tags: python, pandas

QUESTION:

I have a dataframe that I import from a "csv" file with pandas that looks like this (simplified example):

```
id  amount 
1   50     
1   10     
1    5      
2   10     
2   15     
2   25     
2   40
```

So the idea is to sum the amounts and add the result to all records of the same id like this:

```
 id  amount total
1   50     65 
1   10     65 
1   5      65
2   10     90
2   15     90
2   25     90
2   40     90
```

So the resulting dataframe should include an extra column totaling the amount corresponding to each id, but retaining the original dataframe, in order for this to work it's not possible to have a single record per Id with the amount.

I'm working with pandas and manipulating csv files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.join`

```
df.join(df.groupby('id').amount.sum(), rsuffix='_', on = 'id')
```

Output:

```
   id  amount  amount_
0   1      50       65
1   1      10       65
2   1       5       65
3   2      10       90
4   2      15       90
5   2      25       90
6   2      40       90
```

Or even better (thanks [W-B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/w-b)):

```
df.assign(total = df.groupby('id').amount.transform('sum'))
```

output

```
   id  amount  total
0   1      50     65
1   1      10     65
2   1       5     65
3   2      10     90
4   2      15     90
5   2      25     90
6   2      40     90
```

Comment: try transform :-)

Comment: I was trying the jpp way and testing crosstab hehe. My brain is just wired to do it like this :S

Comment: I mean `df.groupby('id').amount.transform('sum')`

Comment: damn, so pretty. I will start doing it this way now. Thanks WB :)